# php mysql get row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to use the mysqli to access a mysql database and a table called phptest, with the code below. I am trying to check if row is = 0 or something else but it does not echo anything. What is wrong with the code?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "phptest");
if (!$mysqli) {
    echo "Can't connect to MySQL Server. Errorcode: %s\n". mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}
$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `test` WHERE `email`='example@hotmail.com' AND `password`='5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99'";
$query_run = $mysqli->query($query);
$row_cnt = $query_run->num_rows;
if ($row_cnt==0) {
    echo 'wrong..';
} else {
    echo 'correct!';
}
```

**EDIT:** edited the variable in the if statement. I have runned the query directly in the mysql panel in the tabel. I get the right row count then. Why doesnt it work in php ?

Comment: `$row_count` is not defined. Turn on strict error reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` and you get a notification.

Comment: I did a mistake, in my file it says $row_cnt instead of count. Have edit it now. but that is not the problem. It seems like the if statement are not being runned or something like that. Any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Although you are checking for an undefined variable `$row_count` (which should be `$row_cnt`, that isn't your immediate problem (you should still fix this). You are getting a fatal error either because:

- Your query is failing. Your query may be failing because of a missing field on the table or indeed you are missing the actual table in the database. The query will return `FALSE` if it fails, but you aren't checking for that, instead you try to access a property of the result. If the query fails, there is no result object, it is a boolean `FALSE` and will produce a fatal error something like `Fatal Error: Trying to access a property of a none object`.
- You don't have the MySQLi library configured for your PHP installation

To further debug you should turn on error reporting as below, or consult your server's error log.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing is that you defined `$row_cnt` and then checked for `$row_count`, but that's just a quick look at your program, so there might be something else wrong too.